# Visual Studio Tabular project ODBC connection

Tags: visual-studio, odbc, business-intelligence

I am trying to connect an SQLite db in a tabular model project. I have used ODBC drivers and the visual studio itself can connect the database but when I try to use table import wizard and select ODBC, I don't see an option for ODBC at all. It is all OLE db. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to pick sqlserver 2019/azure 1500 at the beginning while creating the project.